# Loop bash command until output no longer contains a string

Tags: bash

How to loop `bash` command until output no longer contains a string and then print the time the loop was stopped to output? `watch` command isn't available.

Comment: What's your definition of "not containing a string"?  Do you mean that the output returns numbers only?

Comment: a given string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of running `date +%S`, which prints seconds part of the current time, every half a second and stops on a condition (see below):

```
while true; do
  str=`date +%S`
  echo Output: $str
  # Use the below when you want the output not to contain some string
  if [[ ! $str =~ 5 ]]; then
  # Use the below when you want the output to contain some string
  # if [[ $str =~ 7 ]]; then
    break
  fi
  sleep .5
done
echo Finished: `date`
```

The condition stop:

- If you uncomment this line only:

  ```
  if [[ ! $str =~ 5 ]]; then
  ```

  it will loop while `5` exists in the output (e.g. while from `50` till `00`)
- If you uncomment this line only:

  ```
  if [[ $str =~ 7 ]]; then
  ```

  it will loop until `7` exists in the output (i.e. until current seconds = 07, 17, 27, 37, 47 or 57)

Sample output for not containing string (`5` in this case):

```
Output: 56
Output: 57
Output: 57
Output: 58
Output: 58
Output: 59
Output: 59
Output: 00
Finished: Thu Mar 1 20:16:00 EST 2012
```

Sample output for containing string (`7` in this case):

```
Output: 08
Output: 09
Output: 09
Output: 10
Output: 10
Output: 11
Output: 11
Output: 12
Output: 12
Output: 13
Output: 13
Output: 14
Output: 14
Output: 15
Output: 15
Output: 16
Output: 16
Output: 17
Finished: Thu Mar 1 19:58:17 EST 2012
```

Comment: Could you change that until it doesn't contain the string?

Comment: Sure - just use `if [[ ! $str =~ 5 ]]; then` instead, see my edit.

Comment: bash-2.05$ conditional binary operator expected
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `=~' if [[ ! $str =~ 'NOT successful' ]]; then

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!

Comment: Do you know how to fix the error above? I think it's related to version 2.05 of bash installed on this system.

Comment: Try this: `if [[ \`expr index "$str" 'NOT successful'\` -eq 0 ]]; then`

Comment: It works better than before since the command seems to run, but there is a different error and the loop quits. I inserted \n for newlines. Output: \n
expr: syntax error\n\nOutput is blank where it's supposed to echo $str. If it's relevant, str command contains double quotes: \`"./run a.bash" output\`.

Comment: If you type in plain command prompt `expr index abc b` and get an error, then it's not supported (I'm using bash 4.2.10, so it's a lot newer version). In that case, try this `if [ \`$str|grep 'NOT successful'\` ]; then`. If that doesn't work, then it's time for a bash upgrade :)

Comment: expr index abc b results in expr: syntax error but if [ `$str|grep 'NOT successful'` ]; then results in > prompt.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pastie.org/3507958